# Fill values for multiple dimension array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I want to fill values into a multiple dimension array in R. I know how to implement them in a loop. See below

```
a <- array(seq(1, 8), dim = rep(2, 3))
```

## Case 1

```
b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[2]))
{
    for (j in seq(length = dim(a)[3]))
    {
        b[,i,j] <- b[,1,1]
    }
}
```

i.e - fill first column of first stratum in all other columns:

```
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
```

## Case 2

```
b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[2]))
{
    b[,i,] <- b[,1,]
}
```

i.e. fill first column of each strata in remaining columns of the strata:

```
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    1
#[2,]    2    2
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    5    5
#[2,]    6    6
```

## Case 3

```
b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[3]))
{
    b[,,i] <- b[,,1]
}
```

i.e. fill first strata contents into all other strata:

```
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]    2    4
```

How could I vectorize it? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the generalizations of your for loops using index vectors.

```
a <- array(seq(1, 24), dim = 2:4)

# a couple of handy index vectors
s2 <- seq(length = dim(a)[2])
s3 <- seq(length = dim(a)[3])
```

### Case 1

```
B  <-  b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[2]))
{
    for (j in seq(length = dim(a)[3]))
    {
        b[,i,j] <- b[,1,1]
    }
}


B[,s2,s3] <- B[,1,1]
identical(B,b)
```

### Case 2

```
B  <-  b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[2]))
{
    b[,i,] <- b[,1,]
}

# this is the tricky one.  The assignment works
# because we perumte the the matrix B so that we're 
# assigning to the last index.
B<- aperm(B,c(1,3,2)) 
B[,,s2] <- B[,,1]
B<- aperm(B,c(1,3,2)) 
identical(B,b)
```

### Case 3

```
B  <-  b <- a
for (i in seq(length = dim(a)[3]))
{
    b[,,i] <- b[,,1]
}

B[,,s3] <- B[,,1]
identical(B,b)
```

Comment: Case 1 and Case 3 could just be `a[] <- a[,1,1]` and `a[] <- a[,,1]`